# Where can I ask questions about Android USB Phone Drivers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I faced a problem when I tried to install an Android USB Phone Driver on a Samsung phone I had. It showed an error on my computer when I was installing the driver on the phone using the "Computer Managment" on Windows 7.

The issue was, it showed an error that said it could not find the driver software for my device, even though I selected the right folder which the drivers were in.

I thought about asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), then on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), then on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but then I thought that those might not be the right sites to ask.

Where do you think I can ask this question?

Comment: If it is with the driver I think super user is the right place

Comment: @rene I'll try, let me see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Android Enthusiasts is for Android devices or a particular app that you're facing issue with.

But as you mentioned in the question, you're trying to installing the driver on the phone using the *"Computer Managment" on Windows 7* It should ask on Super User instead.